How to make PyTorch tensor not to change its input format
I have a list of float values like the following which are ids in my data and in the dataset they are originally like 11.0,11.2,16.2,… but when I try to put them in a Data object like the following:
data_with_id = Data(x=x_without_id, edge_index=edge_index.t().contiguous(),edge_weight=edge_feats,y=ground_truth_labels)
        data_with_id.id_column = torch.tensor(id_column, dtype=torch.float)

I see torch.tensor changes the format of them to be like the following:

unique_values: {tensor(11.), tensor(11.2000), tensor(16.2000),
tensor(6.1000), tensor(5006.), tensor(17.), tensor(13.2000),
tensor(19.1000), tensor(2.), tensor(9.), tensor(5010.), tensor(6.),
tensor(14.), tensor(14.1000), tensor(5001.), tensor(5.1000),
tensor(6.2000), tensor(5001.), tensor(4.2000), tensor(11.1000),
tensor(12.), tensor(5007.), tensor(17.1000), tensor(17.),
tensor(4.1000), tensor(8.2000),tensor(19.1000)}

I tried to put them in a set to remove repeated values but still I see repeated values in it. Can anyone suggest me how can I handle it?
Here is what I have tried:
missing_info = []
        unique_values = set()
 
        for i in range(start_timestep-1, start_timestep+ timestep-1):
                if sequence[i].x.size(0) > 0:
                    np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
                    id_column_tensor = torch.tensor(sequence[i].id_column)
                    

                    id_column_list = [float(f"{value:.4f}") if isinstance(value, float) else value for value in id_column_tensor]
                    unique_values.update(id_column_list)
                    
                else:
                    raise ValueError(f"The tensor at sequence[{i}].x is empty.")
   
        print('unique_values:',unique_values)


What do you mean by "change the input format". You are explicitly setting the input format via data_with_id.id_column = torch.tensor(id_column, dtype=torch.float). You set the format and it stays the way you set it

Thank you for your answer. How can I make the format such that to keep the same original format? Now it adds some zeros to the front of each of values for example. For example for 18.1, it changes it to 18.1000. Also my problem is, although I use set() to make all the values unique, still I see repetition after I print the values that are in unique_values.

"For example for 18.1, it changes it to 18.1000."  This has nothing to do with PyTorch. As real numbers, 18.1 and 18.1000 are exactly the same thing (that is, 110^1 + 810^0 + 110^(-1) + 010^(-2) + 0*10^(-3) + …). Are you instead talking about how to print the numbers to screen using a fixed number of digits after the decimal point, or something like that? Then you might want to consider this question and its answers.

Now I am ok with what you said. My problem is How can I also remove repeated values from the set unique_values?

@kami2024: That's a separate question, one that I'm sure you'll find lots of answers to. Hint: The set unique_values will not contain duplicates. If you do find numbers in there you believe are duplicates, then you are probably inspecting/printing those elements with too few digits to see that they are in fact not the same.
